# Recreate rectangle wave animation with a single line

Tags: d3.js, svg

I have this animation that is made up of lots of rectangles 5px wide.

https://codepen.io/guanzo/pen/rmGqNP

You can see it exhibits wave like behavior. This tells me there must be a way to represent this motion with a single curved line, instead of hundreds of rectangles. Most likely using an svg element like `<path>` or `<polyline>`? I think i need to use some modified sine wave function, but i can't wrap my head around the math.

EDIT: 
Managed to get a `polyline` to go up and down with cubicInOut easing.

https://codepen.io/guanzo/pen/vmeoXw

Still no idea how to program the wave like behavior.

EDIT:
My attempt with a `path` and bezier curve transition. Close, but no cigar.

https://codepen.io/guanzo/pen/XRevME?editors=1010

Comment: That curve could be achieved with an svg path with bezier curves, and a transition to animate it. You can also add a gradient and a mask. 

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of animating the line's control points, it would be easier to apply a linear transform to the entire line. Here's a simple example:

```html
<svg width="100%" viewBox="0 0 100 40">
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="40" fill="#fa0" stroke="none"/>
  <path d="M0 0V10H0C20 10 50 30 80 30H120C150 30 150 10 180 10 H220C250 10 250 30 280 30H320C350 30 350 10 380 10H400V-10Z" fill="#c00" stroke="none">
    <animateTransform attributeName="transform" attributeType="XML" type="translate" from="-300 0" to="-100 0" dur="5s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
  </path>
</svg>
```